# How to prevent access to object properties that do not yet exist

Tags: javascript

Often I have this situation:

`var obj = { field: 2 };`

and in the code:

`do_something( obj.fiel );  // note: field spelt wrong`

ie The property is incorrectly typed.  I want to detect these bugs as early as possible.

I wanted to seal the object, ie
`obj = Object.seal(obj);`

But that only seems to prevent errors like `obj.fiel = 2;` and does not throw errors when the field is simply read.

Is there any way to lock the object down so any read access to missing properties is detected and thrown?

thanks,
Paul

EDIT: Further info about the situation

1. Plain javascript, no compilers.
2. Libraries used by inexperienced programmers for math calc purposes.  I want to limit their errors.  I can spot a misspelt variable but they can't.
3. Want to detect as many errors as possible, as early as possible.  ie at compile time (best), at runtime with thrown error as soon as wrong spelling encountered (ok), or when analysing results and finding incorrect calculation outputs (very very bad).
4. Unit tests are not really an option as the purpose of the math is to discover new knowledge, thus the answers to the math is often not known in advance.  And again, inexperienced programmers so hard to teach them unit testing.

Comment: note that any dereference into an _undefined_ variable is a type error.

Comment: are you trying to detect this during development or at runtime?

Comment: If your looking for compile-ish type static tools, look into Typescript.

Comment: Sorry for response delay, the limitations are in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this will work in Javascript since objects are written like JSON and thus properties will be undefined or null but not throw an error.

The solution will be writing a native getter/setter.

```
var obj = {
    vars: {},

    set: function(index, value) {
        obj.vars[index] = value;
    },

    get: function(index) {
        if (typeof(vars[index]) == "undefined") {
            throw "Undefined property " + index;
        }

        return vars[index];
    }
};
```

Comment: That's not true, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4yXj/
Javascript won't throw an error when you use an unexisting property. It will throw an error if you use that undefined property as an object for example: obj.test won't throw an error. However obj.test.x will.

Comment: From the top... alex23 - I wouldn't need try/catch blocks as I would want it to throw and die hard, so errors will be detected and not ignored especially during development.  During runtime too, so users report problems.

Comment: Dillen Miejboom - exactly, and a great point.   However obj.test.y (where y does not exist) won't throw.  Unfortunately.  That would be great, don't you think?

Comment: In the end, I think this is the preferred answer, however there are two concerns:
 1. performance, although its not as bad as I thought: http://jsperf.com/getter-vs-dot-notation
 2. clean code. the inexperienced programmers won't want to type obj.get('x') instead of obj.x and it makes the code a lot harder to read.
But, I can't see any other way, so this is the answer!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable getter/setters in javascript right now. You have to check it manually. Here's a way to do that:

```
if (!('key' in object)) {
    // throw exception
}
```

Comment: That would be a huge typing and performance cost :(  I'm after typo detection rather than explicit checks.

Comment: Thank you Brian, this is similar to Dillen's answer but a lot slower, see: http://jsperf.com/getter-vs-dot-notation

Comment: Very cool that you did a jsperf on it. I never realized the in operator was so slow. Definitely good to see